# TableView Row with a badge number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

How can I add a badge icon to a row in a table view?
An example of this would be the mail app in iOS where the inbox row has a badge icon showing you the number of unread messages?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TDBadgedCell](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell) is a good solution for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create it yourself as there are no template cells for this. Luckily its very simple, create a custom cell with a styled label for the number and update it in cellForRowAtIndexPath: based on the information in your model object.

Answer (score 1):

Either create a custom tableViewCell with a `UILabel` as a subview in it, or add the UILabel to a cell's contentView.

I would recommend creating your own (custom) tableViewCell though.

To get the badge shape for your label, you can play with 'cornerRadius' to get a round shape, and set the `backgroundColor`, `textColor` and `borderWidth`, and `borderColor`.
Once you get the *unreadCount*, just assign it to your customCell's badgeLabel's text property.

Simple as that  !